# Select picture from gallery and exclude a particular folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I am using below code to select picture from gallery -

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String selectedImagePath;
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
            Button btnFolderPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFolderPic);
            Drawable pickedImage = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
            btnFolderPic.setBackgroundDrawable(pickedImage);
            btnFolderPic.setText("");

        }
    }
}
```

It works fine but now I want to exclude some pictures which are in a particular folder so that user can not select those pictures. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> what should i do for that?

Build your own gallery UI, using `MediaStore` as your data source, and arrange to filter out images that you do not want the user to see.

There is nothing in the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` protocol for such filtering, and even if there were, there is no requirement that all implementations of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for images honor the protocol.